# How browser stores the location of visited pages in its History?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner

I am trying to create my own back/forward buttons, so I tried to store visited pages inside an javascript array, but I find that it is hard to maintain visited page locations inside an array.

Can anyone tell, that in which format a browser stores visited page locations in history and how these locations are accessed at the time of pressing back/forward buttons.

Comment: They are not available to you unless you sign your script anyway...

Answer (score 0):

[how to implement back and forward functionality like browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869476/how-to-implement-back-and-forward-functionality-like-browser)

This link also talks about the same thing. The way the browsers keep data might not be available straigh away, but the solution that link speaks about should suffice your need.

Just an add on: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_History_File_Format